# Mysql unique index over 2 fields, is a separate index required for a single field of that set to improve performance?

Tags: mysql

At first, i've already found some answer here: [Would I observe a performance increase if I created a separate index for a single field that was already indexed in a covering index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677401/would-i-observe-a-performance-increase-if-i-created-a-separate-index-for-a-singl)

But the answer is old and maybe not correct anymore for todays technique.
I work on newest MariaDb (10.1) and mysql (5.7.x) server's with InnoDB.

So let's say i have this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` (
    `id` BIGINT(18) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `o` BIGINT(18) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `k` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `v` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ok` (`o`, `k`)
)
```

I want to have best performance for working (order by, where, join, etc..) with `o` and `o`+`k` and also make sure that only one combination of `o`+`k` can exist. Do i require another index for my case?

I assume that it is already best covered by the unique index  `ok` but i'm not that specialist in analysing indexes and their performance. I cannot find any simple explanation when a combined index will be covered and when not.

I always read something with leftmost part will be covered when using combined indexes. What this exactly means? Does it mean the order of fields in the table does matter or the order of the fields in the index itself does matter, or both?

So this here will make use of the index

```
SELECT * FROM `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` WHERE o = 200;
SELECT * FROM `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` ORDER BY o;
```

And this here too

```
SELECT * FROM `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` WHERE o = 200 && k = 'farmer';
SELECT * FROM `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` ORDER BY o, k;
```

And this here not

```
SELECT * FROM `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` WHERE k = 200;
SELECT * FROM `unittest_type_user_dataoptional` ORDER BY k;
```

Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always read something with leftmost part will be covered when using combined indexes. What this exactly means? Does it mean the order of fields in the table does matter or the order of the fields in the index itself does matter, or both?

It means the later. For example if you have an index on `(o,k,v)` it will be used for searches on `o`, `o,k` and `o,k,v` but not on `k` or `k,v`, and only partially for `o,v`. For sorting, it can be used for sorting by `o,k` but not by `k,o`. Pretty much what you said in your question already, it seems you already know that stuff!

The entire chapter 9 in MySQL doc is about optimization, the [section 9.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html) is all about Optimization and Indexes, you'll find all the answers you are looking for there.

> Do i require another index for my case?

No.

Don't forget that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Build the indexes based on the constraints first (primary key, foreign keys and unique keys) and worry about other indexes for pure optimization later. The indexing strategy can change over time, as the table grow and depends on a lot of factors. Don't worry, if you reach a point where you need a different index, you'll know it.